# Powershell Script throws error, when executed via Task Scheduler

Tags: powershell, get, scheduled-tasks, processor

I have a powershell script, which works perfectly fine, when I execute it via the powershell or via right-click --> execute with powershell.
But, when I try to execute it via the Task Scheduler (as Admin and with highes privileges ofc), then it doesn't work.

Now I added a Start-Transcript "..." at the beginning of the script and found that error in the log:

```
get-counter : Unable to connect to the specified computer or the computer is
offline.
At C:\directory\CPU.ps1:72 char:8
+ $CPU = get-counter -Counter "\\$env:computername\processor(_total)\%  ...
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidResult: (:) [Get-Counter], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CounterApiError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Ge
   tCounterCommand
```

That's the full line, that throws the error: **$CPU = get-counter -Counter "\$env:computername\processor(*total)\% processor time" | select -ExpandProperty CounterSamples | select CookedValue | %{[Math]::Round($*.CookedValue,2)}**

Does anybody know, how I can resolve that?

There's no error, when I execute it in powershell or via right click. I don't know how to handle that.

Comment: that may be a permission problem. are you sure that the account used by the task is able to see the target?

Comment: I think so, because It's the user I am logged in to, via Remote Desktop. That user also can execute it directly in the powershell.

Comment: It looks like you are missing an underscore on the `$_` automatic variable here: `Round($.CookedValue,2)`. Also, Since this is run from Task Scheduler, I believe you should not/need not prefix the command with `\\$env:computername`

Comment: I changed "\$env:computername\processor(total)\..." to "\processor(total)\..." still works, when executed via powershell. But same error, when I try to execute it via Task-Scheduler

Comment: @Nanex123 - the error you show means that the account used cannot access the target. that is almost always a permission problem. try taking a look at the info on "double hop problem" for some of the situations & solutions.